# Howto show a filterd list in admin ForeignKey combo box

Tags: django

i have 2 models like bellow.

```
class Student(model.Models):
    SEX = (
        ('MALE', 'MALE'),
        ('FEMALE', 'FEMALE'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)        
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEX)      

class Netball (models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

in the admin Netball insert page under student combo-box i want only to display FEMALE student how can i do this.
is their is any override method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`limit_choices_to=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Netball(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        limit_choices_to={'sex': 'FEMALE'}
    )
```

This will only show `Student`s with `sex='FEMALE'` as options in the `ModelForm` and in the model admin. This will however *not* be enforced at the *database layer*, nor will it thus raise an error if you later change the `sex` of a `Student`. It is thus only validated by the *form* layer at *insertion/update* time of the `Netball`, not of the `Student`.

Comment: thanks its working. but small question if i want to use the similee logic  in product and it have status like sold and unsold. i can filter  unsold buy your method but problem happen when i change the product from unsold to sold on the fly.

Comment: @Kombuwa: no that is not possible. It is not possible to enforce this at the database (unless with triggers, but that is not unversal, and currently Django does not supports this), and at the Django/Python level it would result in some extra querying.